# How can I download this image in Python, without seeing "figure is damaged"?

Tags: python, urllib

I want to dowload an image from http://img13.360buyimg.com/n2/15153/dfa49f49-0e2d-422f-81f9-23a086a7e957.jpg.

But using the following Python code, I get "Figure is damaged". Why?
This is the python code I used to achieve this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(img_url,headers=headers)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing through much easier means if your use requests. If you're new to the whole thing, then requests will be an easy way to do these kinds of things. [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is a link to requests. You can get what you want through a simple requests' get function, so, something like `requests.get(url)`.

And you can save it like this:

```
with open("somefile.jpg","wb") as f:
     f.write(file.content)
```

All the extra documentation that you might need is already on the requests website. In order to install requests, you are going to need `pip` and then use `pip install requests` to install `requests`.

Start using requests now because it makes working with `get` and `post` as well as other kinds of interaction much easier.

Comment: If this answers your question, then please upvote and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the file using urllib.urlretrieve,

```
urllib.urlretrieve("http://img13.360buyimg.com/n2/15153/dfa49f49-0e2d-422f-81f9-23a086a7e957.jpg" , "filename.jpg")
```

more info in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve).

Comment: Thank u! urlretrieve() can also solved my problem. But what is the main difference between urlretrieve and urlopen().read()?